# Web.Config 301 Redirect

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

I am trying to redirect a specific page from my old domain to a specific page on my new domain. The URLs look like the following:

http://blog.mysite.com/post/2012/05/hungry.aspx

to

http://mynewsite.com/hungry.aspx

I've looked to the Web.Config file to make this change, however the following code is not working:

```
<location path="post/2012/05/hungry.aspx">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://mynewsite.com/hungry.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

When I visit my old blog page, it does no redirection and remains on the old blog page.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is http redirection enabled ? see setup section http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have server level access. Is there another way I can check to see if httpRedirect is enabled?

Comment: maybe ask your hosting provider :) don't know any other way

Comment: did you set this on new or old server ?

Comment: Just put in the question to the hosting provider. So awaiting response. I update the Web.Config on the old server, so ideally when someone hits the old site, it redirects them to my new site.

Answer (score 1):

If http redirection is enabled on old server then you have to put new web config in folder post/2012/05/ with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://mynewsite.com/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

btw. if all other options fails you could simply do that using Response.Redirect from code behind.

Comment: The URLs are being written dynamically so I don't have a physical folder at location. I thought I could just write in all the redirects at the root level of the site. No?

Comment: sorry don't know, I was using it this way. Can't you create such folder ?